# Python longest/average 'losing' run in a sequence of binary digits in a string

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have a sequence of events. 1's are good, 0s are bad.
Looking for the most Pythonic way of finding the maximum, minimum and average length of 1 sequences.

For example:

```
seq ="001000000000001101001000000000111100001000000011000010000010001100000110011001000010000010101100001110110001000000100100000011000000001000001000101001000000001000010000010011011000100001000011100000001100010001010100100011011000001000000100010110001101100000000100001000001"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be splitting your string on zeros, dropping empty strings, mapping by length, and sorting:

```
wins = sorted(map(len, filter(None, seq.split("0"))))
```

After that your shortest streak would be at index zero, the longest one would be at the last index (accessible with `-1`) and the average would be easily computable by applying `sum` and dividing by length converted to `float`:

```
print(wins[-1])                     # 4
print(wins[0])                      # 1
print(sum(wins) / float(len(wins))) # 1.4339622641509433
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ywJFku)

Comment: thanks - this version combined with the mean convenience function handled edge cases better

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using list comprehensions and the `len` function to get the list of *wins* length but before that you need to split your string on zeros using the `split` method.

```
seq = "001000000000001101001000000000111100001000000011000010000010001100000110011001000010000010101100001110110001000000100100000011000000001000001000101001000000001000010000010011011000100001000011100000001100010001010100100011011000001000000100010110001101100000000100001000001"
>>> wins_len = [len(el) for el in seq.split('0') if el]
>>> max(wins_len)
4
>>> min(wins_len)
1
```

To compute the average use `sum` and `len`

```
>>> sum(wins_len) / len(wins_len)
1.4339622641509433
```

or the [`mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) function from the [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module new in Python 3.4

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> mean(wins_len)
1.4339622641509433
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very Pythonic, but I would catch all the ones with regex like this :

```
(1{1,})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mE0tA2/1)

and then proceed like this,

```
>>> s=re.findall(r'(1{1,})',a)
>>> length_of_ones=[len(i) for i in s]
>>> max(length_of_ones)
4
>>> min(length_of_ones)
1
>>> sum(length_of_ones)*1.0/len(length_of_ones)
1.4339622641509433
```

where a is your given string.